# How to hide any row in gridview based on any value

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I hide a row based on a certain value in GridView?

For example I have a gridview of five column and when the value of column 3 is blank i don't want to display that row, that row should be hidden. So in gridview only those rows should be visible for which column 3 have any value.
I think that this can be done in GridView's RowDataBound -event, but how can I actually hide it ?

Comment: why fetch the records which have blank properties. make your query such that it fetches accordingly.

Comment: I second Pankajs comment. Theres no point hiding it on the view, when you can do a simple check on the controller. This would save bandwidth and is easy to implement.Just add a where clause to your sql statement.

Answer (score 6):

try this :

```
private void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == "") 
        e.Row.Visible = false;
 }
```

Comment: Just to add some info, Devexpress now recommends using the CustomRowFilter. It works pretty well. https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomRowFiltertopic

Answer (score 2):

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    e.Row.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add RowDataBound event and do like this:

```
if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text == "") e.Row.Visible = false;
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataBound method

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow rw in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        TextBox tx = (TextBox)rw.FindControl("txtHC");

        if (tx.Text == "Value")
            rw.Visible = false; 

    }
}
```